# black screen on new facebook app

Tags: facebook, center

I wonder if anyone has had a problem similar to mine. I built an HTML5 game, and got it hosted and got a security certificate and it all works fine. I went through the tutorial and got it loaded to facebook and was SO grateful, and it went perfect after a few bumps-- and played perfect-- exactly like it was supposed to.

Then I went back and tweaked the source code a little and re-published with my host, then I went back to the facebook app, but the changes were not showing up. I hit "reload" on my google chrome browser window a couple of three times and the last time I got a black screen. I got it on firefox too when I checked, and some of my friends tried it and they had it too. I re-built the app, deleted that one in the app center, re-loaded from scratch under a different name and everything and I still have a black screen. It still works perfect from the website.

Here it is:
"www.facebook.com/appcenter/374750029301876?preview=1&locale=en_US"
I don't know what to do or who to contact but thought i would start here-- and would be grateful for any comment or help.

Comment: Try to be more specific with your problem. Saying that "my app is now broken, can you help" is far to generic for any meaningful responses.

Comment: Hey-- i would have done so, but the software kept dis-allowing my post because there were words in the title and the post and etc. that it didn't like and wouldn't let me post as i originally intended. I am using this site as a kind of booby-prize choice because facebook developer support said to use this when they wouldn't answer my e-mails on their blog. Not really liking it too much right now. By "Not Specific Enough"-- i take that to mean that you have clicked on the links i posted above to take a look at what i am talking about BEFORE flamming me ?? if not-- buzz off.